# Filtered records ids in jqgrid older version 4.1.3

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid older version and I need all filtered records IDs of all pages. Saw the below answer from Stack Overflow, but the below code is not working for me:

```
var oldFrom = $.jgrid.from, lastSelected;

        $.jgrid.from = function (source, initalQuery) {
            var result = oldFrom.call(this, source, initalQuery),
                old_select = result.select;
            result.select = function (f) {
                lastSelected = old_select.call(this, f);
                return lastSelected;
            };
            return result;
        };
```

Comment: Could you verify which version of jqGrid you use (can use)? There is no jqGrid in version 4.1.3. The version history includes 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.2.0, 4.3.0, 4.3.1, ... Probably you use 4.3.1 instead of 4.1.3? By the way [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/GetFilteredData.htm), which I created many years ago uses jqGrid 4.3.1.

Comment: sorry Oleg,,.my jqGrid version is 4.1.2      and there are multiple grids in the same screen. i was not getting lastSelected array in grid[i[.p.data. Now accessing lastSelected array directly solved my issue. Thank you very much for your code on this issue. your code is  great help to me and others who are all having same kind of issue.